# Perl find and replace multiple(huge) strings in one shot

Tags: perl, replace, bulk

Based on a mapping file, i need to search for a string and if found append the replace string to the end of line.
I'm traversing through the mapping file line by line and using the below perl one-liner, appending the strings.

Issues:

**1.Huge find & replace Entries:** But the issues is the mapping file has huge number of entries (~7000 entries) and perl one-liners takes ~1 seconds for each entries which boils down to ~1 Hour to complete the entire replacement.

**2.Not Simple Find and Replace:** Its not a simple Find & Replace. It is - if found string, append the replace string to EOL.
If there is no efficient way to process this, i would even consider replacing rather than appending.

Mine is on Windows 7 64-Bit environment and im using active perl. No *unix support.

**File Samples**

**Map.csv**

```
findStr1,RplStr1

findStr2,RplStr2

findStr3,RplStr3

.....

findStr7000,RplStr7000
```

**input.csv**

```
col1,col2,col3,findStr1,....col-N

col1,col2,col3,findStr2,....col-N

col1,col2,col3,FIND-STR-NOT-EXIST,....col-N
```

**output.csv** (Expected Output)

```
col1,col2,col3,findStr1,....col-N,**RplStr1**

col1,col2,col3,findStr1,....col-N,**RplStr2**

col1,col2,col3,FIND-STR-NOT-EXIST,....col-N
```

**Perl Code Snippet**

**One-Liner**

```
perl -pe '/findStr/ && s/$/RplStr/' file.csv


open( INFILE, $MarketMapFile ) or die "Error occured: $!";
    my @data = <INFILE>;


    my $cnt=1;  
    foreach $line (@data) {
        eval {          
            # Remove end of line character.
            $line =~ s/\n//g;
            my ( $eNodeBID, $MarketName ) = split( ',', $line );
            my $exeCmd = 'perl -i.bak -p -e "/'.$eNodeBID.'\(M\)/ && s/$/,'.$MarketName.'/;" '.$CSVFile;
            print "\n $cnt Repelacing $eNodeBID with $MarketName and cmd is $exeCmd";
            system($exeCmd);
            $cnt++;
        }
    }       
    close(INFILE);
```

Comment: Part of why it takes so long is that you're forking a new Perl process for each line in the loop. You should not do that.

Comment: Will the string you're matching always be in the 4th column of the CSV?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes.The search String column position is fixed always

Comment: You've mentioned that there are ~7000 entries and that the files are "huge"; can you give more information about what that means? How long in characters is a typical entry? How long is the find string? How long is the replace string? Is the find string really just a string or does it have any regex metacharacters e.g.: "$.\"? All of these factors may affect the performance.

Comment: @LenJaffe is on to something but your code snippet isn't just forking. It is forking, then invoking the shell (or possibly execvp), then another perl process is started. This is a lot of overhead.

Comment: @benrifkah Not only that, the OP is reading the entire input file 7000 times, once for each entry in the mapping file.

Comment: Yeah, @ThisSuitIsBlackNot. Since `$CSVFile` is a variable I wasn't sure if the intent was to edit one input file ~7000 times or many so I was waiting to see if more details were forthcoming, before pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in a single pass through your input CSV, it's easiest to store your mapping in a hash. 7000 entries is not particularly huge, but if you're worried about storing all of that in memory you can use [Tie::File::AsHash](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie%3a%3aFile%3a%3aAsHash).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;
use Tie::File::AsHash;

tie my %replace, 'Tie::File::AsHash', 'map.csv', split => ',' or die $!;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1, eol => $/ })
        or die Text::CSV->error_diag;

open my $in_fh, '<', 'input.csv' or die $!;
open my $out_fh, '>', 'output.csv' or die $!;

while (my $row = $csv->getline($in_fh)) {
    push @$row, $replace{$row->[3]};
    $csv->print($out_fh, $row);
}

untie %replace;
close $in_fh;
close $out_fh;
```

*map.csv*

```
foo,bar
apple,orange
pony,unicorn
```

*input.csv*

```
field1,field2,field3,pony,field5,field6
field1,field2,field3,banana,field5,field6
field1,field2,field3,apple,field5,field6
```

*output.csv*

```
field1,field2,field3,pony,field5,field6,unicorn
field1,field2,field3,banana,field5,field6,
field1,field2,field3,apple,field5,field6,orange
```

I don't recommend screwing up your CSV format by only appending fields to matching lines, so I add an empty field if a match isn't found.

To use a regular hash instead of Tie::File::AsHash, simply replace the `tie` statement with

```
open my $map_fh, '<', 'map.csv' or die $!;

my %replace = map { chomp; split /,/ } <$map_fh>;

close $map_fh;
```

Comment: I need to search part of the search string i.e 483338 on 310-120-483338(M). what should i do?

Comment: Do you mean that `483338` is in the mapping file and `310-120-483338(M)` is in the 4th field of the input file?

Comment: Yes... btw in memory is way faster than tie and thanks for the empty column on non-matching lines.i didn't think about it earlier!

Comment: To only match a portion of the 4th field, do something like: `my ($search) = $row->[3] =~ /^\d+-\d+-(\d+)\(M\)$/; push @$row, $replace{$search};` inside the `while` loop, using an appropriate regex for your input.

Comment: You're not actually testing to see if there's a match in the code. I guess that's what I get for not posting a solution that passes 'perl -c' checks...

Comment: @LenJaffe I don't follow you. If there's a matching hash key, the corresponding hash value will be used; if not, `undef`. How is that "not actually testing to see if there's a match"?

Comment: Nope. You're absolutely right. There was too much blood in my caffeine stream.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot one observation I made with this code is, some of the columns which are white-spaced like **2014-03-06 08:00:00,** in original input file is being enclosed by **"2014-03-06 08:00:00",**  Is there any way in perl itself to not to enclose this with "" ? I can handle this out f perl, but just curios?

Comment: @Siva You can change that behavior with the `quote_space` option to `Text::CSV->new`: `Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1, eol => $/, quote_space => 0 })`. [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) has many other options that allow you to fine-tune quoting, escape sequences, etc. which is why I always use it for CSV parsing instead of regexes.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested code / pseudo-Perl you'll need to polish it (strict, warnings, etc.):

```
 # load the search and replace sreings into memeory
 open($mapfh, "<", mapfile);
 %maplines;
 while ( $mapline = <fh> ) {
   ($findstr, $replstr) = split(/,/, $mapline);
   %maplines{$findstr} = $replstr;
 }
 close $mapfh;

 open($ifh, "<", inputfile);
 while ($inputline = <$ifh>) {                 # read an input line
   @input = split(/,/, $inputline);           # split it into a list

   if (exists $maplines{$input[3]}) {        # does this line match
     chomp $input[-1];                       # remove the new line
     push @input, $maplines{$input[3]};      # add the replace str to the end
     last;                                   # done processing this line
   }
   print join(',', @input);  # or print or an output file 
 }

 close($ihf)
```