# perl hash mapping/retrieval issues with split and select columns

Tags: perl, hashmap

[Perl find and replace multiple(huge) strings in one shot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230747/perl-find-and-replace-multiplehuge-strings-in-one-shot)

P.S.This question is related to the answer for above question.

When I try to replace this code:

**Snippet-1**

```
open my $map_fh, '<', 'map.csv' or die $!;
my %replace = map { chomp; split /,/ } <$map_fh>;
close $map_fh;
```

with this code:

**Snippet-2**

```
my %replace = map { chomp; (split /,/)[0,1] } <$map_fh>;
```

even though the key exists (as in the dumper), **exists** statement doesn't return the value for the key.

For same input file, it works perfectly with just split alone (Snippet-1) whereas not returning anything when i select specific columns after split(Snippet-2).

Is there some integer/string datatype mess-up happening here?

**Input Mapping File**

```
483329,Buffalo

483330,Buffalo

483337,Buffalo
```

**Script Output**

```
$VAR1 = {
          '483329' => 'Buffalo',
          '46546' => 'Chicago_CW',
          '745679' => 'W. Washington',
        };
1 search is ENB 
2 search is 483329 **expected Buffalo here**
3 search is 483330 
4 search is 483337
```

**Perl Code**

```
open my $map_fh, '<', $MarketMapFile or die $!;

if ($MapSelection =~ /eNodeBID/i) {
    my %replace = map { chomp; (split /,/)[0,1] } <$map_fh>;
    use Data::Dumper;
    print Dumper(\%replace);
}
close $map_fh;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1, eol => $/,quote_space => 0 });
my $tmpCSVFile = $CSVFile."tmp";

open my $in_fh, '<', $CSVFile or die $!;
open my $out_fh, '>', $tmpCSVFile or die $!;
my $cnt=1;

while (my $row = $csv->getline($in_fh)) {
    my $search = $row->[5];
    $search =~ s/[^[:print:]]+//g;
    if ($MapSelection =~ /eNodeBID/i) {
        $search =~ s/(...)-(...)-//g;
        $search =~ s/\(M\)//g;
    }       

    my $match = (exists $replace{$search}) ? $replace{$search} : undef;
    print "\n$cnt search is $search ";
    if (defined($match)) {
        $match =~ s/[^[:print:]]+//g;
        print "and match is $match";
    }

    push @$row, $match;

    #print "  match is $match"; 
    $csv->print($out_fh, $row);
    $cnt++;
}

# untie %replace;
close $in_fh;
close $out_fh;
```

Comment: Please be clear about what you are replacing.  Is it just the one line you are replacing, or that whole snippet 1?

Comment: @mareoraft Just one line

Comment: Can you also give the input value of $MapSelection?

Comment: It would be good to see the Script Output for both Snippet1 and Snippet2.  Right now there is only one of them, which I am assuming is for Snippet2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem of scope.  Your code:

```
if ($MapSelection =~ /eNodeBID/i) {
    my %replace = map { chomp; (split /,/)[0,1] } <$map_fh>;
    use Data::Dumper;
    print Dumper(\%replace);
}
```

declares `%replace` within the `if` block.  Move it outside so that it can also be seen by later code:

```
my %replace;
if ($MapSelection =~ /eNodeBID/i) {
    %replace = map { chomp; (split /,/)[0,1] } <$map_fh>;
    use Data::Dumper;
    print Dumper(\%replace);
}
```

Putting `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of your code helps you find these kinds of issues.

Also, you can just use `my $match = $replace{$search}` since it's equivalent to your `?:` operation.

Answer (score 2):

Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of EVERY perl script.  If you had done that and been maintaining good coding practice with declaring your variables, you would've gotten error:

```
Global symbol "%replace" requires explicit package name at
```

That would've let you know there was a scoping issue with your code. One way to avoid that is to use a ternary in your initialization of `%replace`

```
my %replace = ($MapSelection =~ /eNodeBID/i)
    ? map { chomp; (split /,/)[0,1] } <$map_fh>
    : ();
```